# Error: cannot open URL when installing private R package which depends on second private R package

Tags: devtools, r-package, remotes

i have two r packages pkg1 and pkg2 hosted on a self-hosted gitlab instance. The packages are located in group1/r-packages. Group1 is a project group.

pkg2 depends on pkg1.

I want to install pkg2 via devtools::install_gitlab(repo = 'group1/r-packages/pkg2', host = 'gitlab.hostname', auth_token = '<access_token').

The access token used was created for the r-packages subgroup.

Within the DESCRIPTION file of pkg2 i have listed pkg1 in Imports as well as in Remotes with 'gitlab@hostname::group1/r-packages/pkg1'.

I get the following error message trying to install pkg2:

"Failed to install 'pkg2' from GitLab: cannot open URL 'https://hostname/api/v4/projects/group1%2Fr-packages%Fpkg1/repository/files/DESCRIPTION/raw?ref=HEAD'"

I already tried a different statement in Remotes (DESCRIPTION) as stated here for example: [How do you specify GitLab host in Remotes section of DESCRIPTION file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61502932/how-do-you-specify-gitlab-host-in-remotes-section-of-description-file).

Answer (score 0):

I did not write the full hostname for the gitlab instance.

Full hostname: https://gitlab.nameOfPrivateInstance.net

So changing the remotes part in the DESCRIPTION File:

- from: gitlab@nameOfPrivateInstance.net::group1/r-packages/pkg1
- to: gitlab@https://gitlab.nameOfPrivateInstance.net::group1/r-packages/pkg1

solved it for me.